Call to undefined method Drupal\commerce\PurchasableEntityInterface::getProduct
I have code which should return get the actual product (not variation).
The problem is that phpstan/drupal-checker (mglaman/drupal-check) returns this error.

Call to an undefined method Drupal\commerce\PurchasableEntityInterface::getProduct().

The code I am using is the following one.
public function applies(OrderItemInterface $order_item) {
  $product = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity()->getProduct();

  return $product instanceof ProductInterface;
}

$product is in fact an instance of a class that implements ProductInterface. Why does the error indicate that getProduct() is an undefined method? How can I fix that?

@monalisa it doesn't change the output of phpstan. So it's not possible to fix as far as i can see.

How would we know without seeing your code change? I've used PHPStan for many years and I understand it and PHP typing analysis pretty well.

I can second what @monalisa is saying. OrderItemInterface::getPurchasedEntity() is not type hinted to return something which has a getProduct method, hence the error. If you know better, that the object does have that method in this context, then type hint it as such; that’s why type hinting exists after all. If you want even more robust code, check the type of the object is instanceof ProductInterface before you use a method from that class. Simples.

You have to put a @var comment over $product = with ProductInterface. But phpstan may actually be showing a bug in your code. It would be better to test the type of $order_item->getPurchasedEntity() before continuing.
